# getSequencer() генерирует исключение

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Имеется код:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Tester t1 = new Tester();
            t1.play();
    }   
    public void play(){
        try{
            Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            System.out.println("Done");
        }catch(MidiUnavailableException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Во время выполнения постоянно выбрасывается исключение, вот что выводит программа:

```
javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: Undefined external error.
```

В документации написано вот что:

> **Throws:**  MidiUnavailableException - if the sequencer is not available
>   due to resource restrictions, or no sequencer is installed in the
>   system, or if connected is true, and there is no Receiver available by
>   any installed MidiDevice

Подскажите как с этим бороться? Я правильно понимаю что в системе не хватает чего то? Может драйвера установить нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблема решилась после подключение к компьютеру наушников. До этого ничего не было подключено.